# why there is "l" before landroid/view/keyevent

Tags: java, android

why there is "l" before the name of the class in: "landroid/view/keyevent"
Does it have a special meaning? Is it possible to use android/view/keyevent? what is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how [`Class#getName()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Class#getName()) encodes type information. `L` denotes a class or interface type.

A typical way to see that is via the default implementation of `Object#toString()`:

```
public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```